# How to transfer comments when transferring data from one table to another in Google Sheet with the QUERY+IMPORTRANGE function

Tags: google-sheets

comments transferred
How are comments written in cells transferred when data is moved
From one Google Sheet table to another while using a function
QUERY+IMPORTRANGE
[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it's not possible to show notes or comments by using [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

You can [fill out a Feature Idea](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762) to add that functionality into Google Sheets on https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Feature-Ideas/gh-p/workspace-ideas-group

As a workaround, if you copy and paste the cells, comments and notes will be copied over, but you can do it programmatically in Google Apps Script by using [`copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

```
// The code below copies the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 5);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 6));
```

Comment: I am very thankful for your help